# Number of Turing machines

Tags: computational-complexity, automata, turing-machines

Do you have any idea about this question? I do not know what it asks.

-What is the number of Turing machines with with the state set  $\{Q-\text{start}, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q-\text{accept}, Q-\text{reject}\}$, input alphabet $\{0,1\}$ and tape alphabet $\{0,1,\text{x},\text{U}\}$ where $\text{U}$ is the blank symbol? The start, accept and reject states are the ones with the appropriate names. Show your work.

Comment: It looks clear enough to me. The question asks how many possible ways there are to fill out the transition table given this number of states and alphabet sizes.

Comment: You mean going right and left in tape?

Comment: I mean _the entire transition table_, and everything in it.

Comment: Nice question.  ***Endorsed.*** I edited your text to $\LaTeX$ify the math.  Cheers!

Comment: could you show me an example please ?

Comment: My pleasure, sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the *quadruple* formalization of Turing-machines, every transition is of the form $<Q_i, S_j, A_{ij}, Q_{ij}>$: 'If you arer in state $Q_i$ and read symbol $S_j$, perform action $A_{ij}$ (which is *either* to move left or right *or* print a symbol), and go to new state $Q_{ij}$:

you have $6$ choices for $Q_i$ (the $Q_{Accept}$ and $Q_{Reject}$ do not have any outgoing transitions)

You have $4$ choices for the symbol you are reading

You have $6$ choices for the action: move left, move right, or print any of the $4$ symbols

You have $8$ choices for the new state

So: for each of the $6\cdot 4 = 24$ entries in the transition-table, you have $6\cdot8=48$ possibilities, giving you $48^{24}$ possible Turing-machines using the quadruple formalization.

Assuming the *quintuple* formalization of Turing-machines, every transition is of the form $<Q_i, S_j, S_{ij}, A_{ij}, Q_{ij}>$: 'If you are in state $Q_i$ and read symbol $S_j$, print out symbol $S_{ij}$, perform action $A_{ij}$ (move left or right), and go to new state $Q_{ij}$:

you have $6$ choices for $Q_i$ (the $Q_{Accept}$ and $Q_{Reject}$ do not have any outgoing transitions)

You have $4$ choices for the symbols you are reading

You have $4$ choices for the symbol you are writing

You have $2$ choices for the action: move left or move right

You have $8$ choices for the new state

So: for each of the $6\cdot 4 = 24$ entries in the transition-table, you have $4\cdot2\cdot8=64$ possibilities, giving you $64^{24}$ possible Turing-machines using the quintuple formalization.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got everything except the last 8 choices for new state. Why 8  choices?

Comment: @myadsmail There are $8$ states that any transition can go to: $Q_{Start}, Q_2, Q_3, Q_4, Q_5, Q_6, Q_{Accept}, Q_{Reject}$ ... unless a machine can never go back to $Q_{Start}$ ... but I have never seen something like that.  But you may want to ask about that: can the machine ever transition back to $Q_{Start}$?  If not, then there are only $7$ states that the transition can go to, *and* since the input only consists of $0$ and $1$ there would be no transitions going out of $Q_{Start}$ for the $*$ and *U* ... again, I have never seen anything like that, but you never know ...